# Parsing website with Hpricot

Tags: ruby, rubygems, hpricot

I'm trying to parse images from reddit using Ruby and the Hpricot gem.

Using Chrome I got the XPath to the div holding the link to the image then I use doc.search to find it but the results come up empty.

```
doc.search('//*[@id="siteTable"]/div[1]/a').each do |r|
    puts r.attributes['href']
end
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post example code that sets the doc variable from the page on Reddit you are trying to parse?

Comment: Each link has a 'thumbnail' class anyway, so just use that. With Nokogiri: `ruby -rnokogiri -ropen-uri -e 'puts Nokogiri.HTML(open("http://www.reddit.com")).search("a.thumbnail").map { |a| a[:href] }'`

Comment: Don't use hpricot, use Nokogiri. It works better and is the defacto standard for Ruby.